# Why doesn't this if-statement work with && and || in same if

Tags: if-statement

```
    else if((op1 == "*" || op1 == "/" )&& (op2 == '+' || op2 == '-'))
        return true;
```

my op1 is *     my op2 is +
but im still return false

Comment: please share a full snippet, staring at least from the `if`. Also - what programming language is this?

Comment: your posted condition should return true only. post full code

Comment: Add a language tag

Answer (score 0):

You are using double quotes for multiplication operator and division operator, but single quotes for addition operator and subtraction operator.
As others have commented, the language is relevant.
In C for example comparing a variable of type "char" to a single quote literal is OK, but comparing a char to a double quote constant, i.e. a string, is questionable.
If this is C, try to change

```
op1 == "*" || op1 == "/"
```

to

```
op1 == '*' || op1 == '/'
```

You might also want to use more "()".

```
(op1 == '*') || (op1 == '/')
```

I guess this (i.e. operator precedence) is not relevant here, but it generally helps avoiding confusion.